# Collections of Custom Views for Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view

Does anyone know some existing and free to use collection of custom views? Or some framework which would make it a little easier to create custom views (e.g. just a SimpleCustomView class extending the View class). The newer versions of the SDK allow very fast and nice prototyping because the custom view can be tested directly in the xml layout file but I cant find a lot of information or any existing projects.

Comment: What are you expecting this "existing and free to use collection of custom views" to do?

Comment: For example some utility classes for canvas, bitmap, vector manipulation and of course some example implementations how to do it right. Another thing would be a 2D vector class for custom drawing. And it is really hard to not crash the UI editor with your custom views at the moment and because all of this i think it would be really good to have some working examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it's a little too late but [AndroidViews](http://www.androidviews.net/) has quite a nice compilation of the great custom Views out there.

Answer (score 1):

Here as [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos&hl=en) where you can preview some custom views